# If statement is being ignored from Checkbox

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I am using five checkboxes to make a pizza app. The checkboxes are labeled Plain, Ex Cheese, Pepperoni, Green Peppers, and Sausage. There is also a button that when clicked will show a picture of the constructed pizza depending upon what checkboxes were clicked.

**XML code**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tablerow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkbox1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:text="@string/Plain"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkbox2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:text="@string/Ex_Cheese"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tablerow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkbox3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:text="@string/Pepperoni"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkbox4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:text="@string/GPepper"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tablerow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkbox5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:text="@string/Sausage"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:text="@string/Button1"
                android:textColor="#000000" 
                android:onClick="Order"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Java Code**
    package com.example.pizza_app_v1;

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

/** Button Click event*/ 
public void Order (View view){
    CheckBox plain = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox1);
    CheckBox Ex_Cheese = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox2);
    CheckBox Pepperoni = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox3);
    CheckBox GreenPep = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox4);
    CheckBox Sausage = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox5);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    if (plain.isChecked()){
        Ex_Cheese.setChecked(false);
        Pepperoni.setChecked(false);
        GreenPep.setChecked(false);
        Sausage.setChecked(false);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.a_plain);
    }

    if (Pepperoni.isChecked() && Ex_Cheese.isChecked() == false){
        if(Pepperoni.isChecked() && GreenPep.isChecked() && Sausage.isChecked() == false ){
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.f_pep_gp);
        } else if(Pepperoni.isChecked() && Sausage.isChecked() && GreenPep.isChecked() == false){
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.c_pep);
        } else if(Pepperoni.isChecked() && GreenPep.isChecked() && Sausage.isChecked()){
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.p_pep_gp_sau);
        } else {
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.c_pep);
        }

    if(GreenPep.isChecked() && Ex_Cheese.isChecked() == false ){
        if(GreenPep.isChecked() && Sausage.isChecked() && Pepperoni.isChecked() == false ){
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.g_gp_sau);
        } else{
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.b_gp);
        }
    }
```

The problem that I am having is that the second if statement=> if(GreenPep.isChecked() &&...) is being ignored. In the application if Green Peppers is checked no image will appear. The same applies for when green peppers and sausage is checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't close the bracket for the previous if statement:

```
if (Pepperoni.isChecked() && Ex_Cheese.isChecked() == false){
    if(Pepperoni.isChecked() && GreenPep.isChecked() && Sausage.isChecked() == false ){
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.f_pep_gp);
    } else if(Pepperoni.isChecked() && Sausage.isChecked() && GreenPep.isChecked() == false){
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.c_pep);
    } else if(Pepperoni.isChecked() && GreenPep.isChecked() && Sausage.isChecked()){
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.p_pep_gp_sau);
    } else {
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.c_pep);
    }
```

Comment: If you avoid reusing tests that have already passed, you'll make your code easier to read, as well. Anything inside that if statement will only execute if `Pepperoni.isChecked()` is true, so you don't need to keep on testing that in the inner if statements.

Comment: @Simes Yes I agree, but i started adding those before I knew I had missed a bracket. At first I thought the code was getting hung up in the first if(Pepperoni.isChecked()) statement.